# How to set jquery variable value to Viewbag or ViewData

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I will try to make button click event using jquery.
but I do not know way how I can pass jquery variable value in Viewbag or
ViewData

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general handling click event is solved by `.click(function())` method or `.on('click', function())`. After handling the click event and then sending a http POST/GET request to pass the data to your server-side application.

Example snippet would look like:

```
$('#button-id').click(function(){
    // Click handle 
    $.post("/url/to/controller", $( "#form-id" ).serialize() ); // send data to controller
});
```

And then handle the input in the controller.